# Given the commit hash of a fix,how could I get the figure out how exactly the code is fixed?

Tags: git, git-commit

Suppose I have the commit hash of a fix that fixes a bug. I would like to know how exactly the developer changed to code in that fix. What is the git command line for me to get me the info? Should I do something like

```
git diff <fix-hash> <before-fix-hash>
```

I an unsure whether this would be the right direction, and I do not see how to get the  part Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do

```
git show <commit hash>
```

To see what changed in that particular commit that led to the fix. Is this you're asking?

Comment: Another way is: git diff <commit-hash>^!